# Opens...and leaves?

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

Can we say "He opens the door and leaves" or is it better to say "He opens the door and leave"?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Subject-Verb
Agreement](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm).

Answer (score 1):

It should read:

> He opens the door and leaves.

Your subject (He) is singular, so your verbs (open and leave) should be singular (perhaps confusingly, in the English language this often means adding an 's' to the end of the verb when speaking in the third-person).

Comment: Opens and leaves, as verbs, are singular, not plural.

Comment: @StevenLittman I never knew you were supposed to call them singular verbs even though as words they have the s on the end. How would you say it then, that 'the verbs should have an s on the end'? I think my response will probably be clear to a non-english speaker though.

Comment: No it will not be clear. "Opens" is the _third-person singular_of "to open"; "leaves" is the _third-person singular_ of "to leave".  An **S** on the end does not make a verb plural (nor does it necessarily indicate a plural form for a noun).

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Thanks for the clarification. It's been a long while since I've taken an english class.

Comment: @spacetyper - please edit your answer, and change the last word to "singular".

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast it's edited, but you can feel free to post an answer yourself or edit it if you feel it's wrong/still confusing.

Answer (score 0):

All verbs must agree with their subject, no matter how many there are in one sentence. Even though *leaves* is separated from the subject *he*, it is still *he* who does that action.

A further example:

> He opens the door, spins around to say goodbye to his son Jason, eats the last bite of the feta and tomato sandwich he had been munching on, and leaves.

All verbs in that sentence are in the third person singular form, no matter how far they get from their subject.